# Converting float to char*

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

How can I convert a `float` value to `char*` in `C` language?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What do you want - a textual representation of the decimal value of the float? A stream of bytes you can pass around easily and use to reconstitute the float later?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
char buffer[64];
int ret = snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%f", myFloat);

if (ret < 0) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
if (ret >= sizeof buffer) {
    /* Result was truncated - resize the buffer and retry.
}
```

That will store the string representation of `myFloat` in `myCharPointer`. Make sure that the string is large enough to hold it, though.

`snprintf` is a better option than `sprintf` as it guarantees it will never write past the size of the buffer you supply in argument 2.

Answer (score 15):

In Arduino:

```
//temporarily holds data from vals
char charVal[10];                

//4 is mininum width, 3 is precision; float value is copied onto buff
dtostrf(123.234, 4, 3, charVal);

monitor.print("charVal: ");
monitor.println(charVal);
```

Answer (score 12):

```
char array[10];
sprintf(array, "%f", 3.123);
```

[sprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf%28VS.71%29.aspx): (from MSDN)

Comment: @aJ When the value is printed in buffer will the same print statement be printed on console as well....

Comment: sprintf will write the float value in buffer. If you want to print the same to console use printf("%f" ...

Answer (score 10):

Long after accept answer.

Use `sprintf()`, or related functions, as many others have answers suggested, but use a better format specifier.

Using `"%.*e"`, code solves various issues:

- The maximum buffer size needed is far more reasonable with `"%.*e"`, like 18 for `float` (see below). With `"%f"`, (think *fixed-point*), `sprintf(buf, "%f", FLT_MAX);` could need 47+ `char`. `sprintf(buf, "%f", DBL_MAX);` may need 317+ `char`.
- Using `".*"` allows code to define the number of decimal places needed to distinguish a string version of `float x` and it next highest `float`.  For details, see [printf width specifier to maintain precision of floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16839658/printf-width-specifier-to-maintain-precision-of-floating-point-value)
- Using `"%e"` allows code to distinguish small `float`s from each other rather than all printing `"0.000000"` which is the result when `|x| < 0.0000005` with `"%f"`.

Example usage:

```
#include <float.h>
#define FLT_STRING_SIZE (1+1+1+(FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1)+1+1+ 4   +1)
                     //  - d .  dddddddd           e - dddd \0

char buf[FLT_STRING_SIZE];
sprintf(buf, "%.*e", FLT_DECIMAL_DIG-1, some_float);
```

Ideas:
IMO, better to use 2x buffer size for scratch pads like `buf[FLT_STRING_SIZE*2]`.
For added robustness, use `snprintf()`.

---

As a 2nd alterative consider `"%.*g"`.  It is like `"%f"` for values exponentially  near 1.0  and like `"%e"` for others.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* str=NULL;
int len = asprintf(&str, "%g", float_var);
if (len == -1)
  fprintf(stderr, "Error converting float: %m\n");
else
  printf("float is %s\n", str);
free(str);
```

Comment: +1 even though it must specified it is a GNU extension afaik. (asprintf is a GNU ext I mean)

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef union{
    float a;
    char b[4];
} my_union_t;
```

You can access to float data value byte by byte and send it through 8-bit output buffer (e.g. USART) without casting.

Comment: Upd: do not forget about processor's endianness!

Comment: type `unsigned char` is highly advisable for the array in this union.

Comment: Yes. I use uint8_t. BTW the simplest (but not safe) way is just to cast pointers ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
char array[10];
snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "%f", 3.333333);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// float arr to bytes
int arr_len = 3;
float x[3] = {1.123, 2.123, 3.123};
char* bytes = new char[arr_len * sizeof(float)];
memcpy(bytes, x, arr_len * sizeof(float));

// bytes to float arr
float y[3];
memcpy(y, bytes, arr_len * sizeof(float));
```

Comment: Please provide more supporting information to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Convert float to binary via ascii codes

```
float u = 2.154328
string s = to_string(u);
char* p = (char*) s;
```

This stores the characters, 2, .,1, 5, ...,
or in binary
00000010,00101110, 00000001, ...

Comment: This is not `C`.