# Reconstructiong float value from UART char array

Tags: python, stm32, uart

I am trying to send float values over UART to a PC and reconstruct these float values from their respective char array. How I am transferring the 32-bit float value to char is below:

```
  float value = 42.83f;
  unsigned char *ptr = &value;
```

And in the Python script received value is:

```
[236, 81, 43, 66, 4, 42]
```

How can I cast this char array back to `42.83f`?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Bytes to Floating Point Numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415/convert-bytes-to-floating-point-numbers)

Comment: Also relevant: [How are floating point numbers stored in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644699/how-are-floating-point-numbers-stored-in-memory)

Comment: @alagner it kind of helps, however, I get the error "unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes" this is my buffer at the moment and it seems fine to me: b'\xea\xa6\x9a@\x04*'

Comment: @doeppler mind the spaces I've added: b'\xea \xa6 \x9a @ \x04 *' - that's obviously 6 bytes.

Comment: @alagner It's too bad I can't mark your comment as an answer but you helped me. So, thank you!

Comment: @doeppler you're welcome ;) I wonder though how you're serializing and sending the data so you receive too much, but that's a topic for another question.

Comment: @alagner I use the ST-HAL from STM. The snippet of the code is below. I am always up for more learning :)

float value[3] = {1.23, 2.23, 5.13};
  unsigned char *ptr = &value;

HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, ptr, strlen(ptr), 100);

Comment: @doeppler you might want to read that: [Converting float to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988791/converting-float-to-char).

Answer (score 0):

The way I decoded may be strange perhaps but I was receiving two elements more than needed for a float decode. Currently this is my shortcut solution:
I pop the last two elements from the list meaning that I have 4 bytes left instead of 6 bytes. Then I use the following code to reconstruct the float value.

```
print("Processing...")
# process the data block
result_data.pop()
result_data.pop()
bytes_of_result = bytes(result_data)
print(bytes_of_result)
final_value = struct.unpack('f', bytes_of_result)
print(final_value)
```