# Float to char array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I trying to merge all members of a float array in a char array.

This is float array :

```
float myFloatArray[2] = {10,20};
```

And this is char array :

```
char myCharArray[32];
```

I want to set char array like "1020"

in C# i can do it like this;

```
string myStr =  myFloatArray[0] + myFloatArray[1];
```

but how can i do this in C?

Comment: The line `string myStr = myFloatArray[0] + myFloatArray[1];` [will not compile in C#](https://godbolt.org/z/YPKcxehvn). Do you mean `string myStr = myFloatArray[0].ToString() + myFloatArray[1].ToString();`?

Comment: MBK Software, How would you want `{1,20}` and `{12,0}` to print out? Or `{1,2,3}` vs. `{123};` vs. `{12. 30, 0};`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have two numbers to be converted, then you can simply write

```
snprintf(
    myCharArray, sizeof myCharArray,
    "%.0f%.0f",
    myFloatArray[0],
    myFloatArray[1]
);
```

Here is a working example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float myFloatArray[2] = {10,20};
    char myCharArray[32];
    snprintf(
        myCharArray, sizeof myCharArray,
        "%.0f%.0f",
        myFloatArray[0],
        myFloatArray[1]
    );

    printf( "%s\n", myCharArray );
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
1020
```

Comment: I would do just `%.0f`.

Comment: @KamilCuk: Yes, you are correct. That solution is much simpler. Thanks for pointing it out. I have taken it over.

Comment: @MBKSoftware: In my example above, `myCharArray[0]` has the value `'1'`, because that is the first character of the string `"1020"`. What makes you think that it has the value "null"?

Comment: @MBKSoftware: As you can see in [this demonstration](https://godbolt.org/z/rvaPoexj3), `myCharArray[0]` has the value `49`, which is the ASCII character code for the digit `1`. Therefore, as far as I can tell, my solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use `sprintf` to convert the first and second elements of the float array to strings, and concatenate them into the char array. The "%.0f" format specifier tells sprintf to format the float value as an integer.

```
sprintf(myCharArray, "%.0f%.0f", myFloatArray[0], myFloatArray[1]);
```

Also notice the answer provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988791/converting-float-to-char) where `snprintf` is suggested for safety reasons.

```
snprintf(myCharArray, sizeof(myCharArray), "%.0f", myFloatArray[0]);
snprintf(myCharArray+strlen(myCharArray), sizeof(myCharArray)-strlen(myCharArray), "%.0f", myFloatArray[1]);
```